# rabbit birth. Feels like babys

Tags: rabbits

My rabbit still feels and looks like she is pregnant, she had 7 babies and it is the 4 day after birth. Could she still have a baby in her ? I repalpated her and i can feel 1 full size baby and a ball

Comment: Was your buck in with the doe, after she got pregnant with first litter?

Comment: I have updated the answer at the related question to include info about Superfetation (double pregnancy) and voted to close this question as duplicate.

Comment: No i spilt the the rabbits up

Comment: Going to a vet is an obvious choice you should make... That aside, and given the existing question and answer.  You might want to focus on the risks and time frames of the mother reabsorbing a kit she did not deliver. You can ask another question, reword this question, or leave me a note and I will try to refocus the question to things that you should worry about that we do not already have an answer for.